# Digits recognition with rules

Tags: python, neural-network

I am looking to extract and identify digits from an image.
I've read a lot about digits recogntion but did not find anything on adding rules to select the only the digits we are interest in.

The rules would be "quite simple" I want to extract only the digits surrounded with a blue pen for example.

Not waiting for the entire solution here but more a axes of researches or links to similir problem.
[image: Sample]

I am quite familiar with Neural Networks and intend to use one on this. But I cannot see how filter out only the surrounded digits.

Here a sample of the picture. Image the same schema but several times on a picture.

Comment: why not training a neural network to only find pictures that are sourounded and train anotuer one (or do it in the same, might also work) to recognize the digit

Comment: Well I have like 50 digits on the image and only 5 are surrounded.

Comment: Can you share image sample? Solution really depends on quality and type of drawings.

Comment: I Added a sample

Comment: Have a look at the approach outlined here -> https://medium.com/@waleedka/traffic-sign-recognition-with-tensorflow-629dffc391a6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have three ways of operating. And maybe you do not need to get that far! For now, we will only look for which one has been selected.

**Case 1:** You can try to use the hough transform for circles to find the circles present in the image.

```matlab
% Solution 1 (practically a perfect cicle, use hough circle transform to find circles)
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7cE1.png');
[centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(im, [10, 60]);
imshow(im); viscircles(centers, radii,'EdgeColor','r');
```

**Case 2:** You can work in the space of the blue color and eliminate achromatic colors to segment the areas that interest you (If you add margins you can work correctly).

```matlab
% Solution 2 (ALWAYS is blue, read only rgB channel and delete achromatic)
b = im(:, :, 3) & (std(double(im(:, :, :)), [], 3) > 5);
bw = imfill(b,'holes');
stats = regionprops('table', bw, 'Centroid', 'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength')
imshow(im); viscircles(stats.Centroid, stats.MajorAxisLength / 2,'EdgeColor','r');
```

**Case 3:** You can generate a dataset together with positive cases and others with negative ones. And train a neural network with 10 outputs that indicate in each one if there is or not crossed out (sigmoid output). The good thing about this type of model is that you should not do an OCR later.

```py
import keras
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
from keras.losses import mean_squared_error
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
def model():
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 128, 128
    mobile_input = Input(shape=(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3))
    alpha = 0.25 # 0.25, 0.5, 1
    shape = (1, 1, int(1024 * alpha))
    dropout = 0.1
    input_ = Input(shape=(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3))
    mobile_model = MobileNet(input_shape=(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3), 
                             alpha= alpha, 
                             include_top=False, 
                             dropout = dropout,
                             pooling='avg')
    base_model = mobile_model(mobile_input)
    x = Reshape(shape, name='reshape_1')(base_model)
    x_gen = Dropout(dropout, name='dropout')(x)
    x = Conv2D(10, (1, 1), padding='same')(x_gen)
    x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
    output_detection = Reshape((10,), name='output_mark_detection')(x)

    """x = Conv2D(2 * 10, (1, 1), padding='same')(x_gen)
    x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
    output_position = Reshape((2 * 10, ), name='output_mark_position')(x)
    output = Concatenate(axis=-1)([output_detection, output_position])
    """

    model = Model(name="mark_net", inputs=mobile_input, outputs=output_detection)
```

It depends on your problem, the first cases can serve you. In case of having different conditions of lighting, rotation, scaling, etc. I advise you to go directly to neural networks, you can create many "artificial" examples:

1. You can generate an artificial dataset by adding distorted
   circles (take a normal circle apply random
   affine transformations, add noise, change a little the blue color,
   the line, etc).
2. Then you paste the randomly circle in each number and
   generate the dataset indicating which numbers are marked.
3. Once "stuck on the paper" you can apply the data augmentation again
       to make it look more real.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the problem in two simpler sub-problems: you could train a first neural network to recognize circles and isolate them. Once you did, you can then train a second neural network to recognize the digits within the subsection you isolated. Hope this helps.

Comment: Any suggestion of tutorial/example for the circle isolation?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the first time I encountered this classification problem. However, I think building your own training set should take a reasonable amount of time. Sorry!